# cannot import win32api and win32con in visual studio python

Tags: python, module

i am trying to import win32api and win32con into my python project . i have installed pypiwin32 and pywin32 from PyPi , but when i try to import win32api , win32con , i get a green underline under win32api and win32con , and when i hover over the green line , a pop-up says "unresolved import 'win32api'"

here's the code :

```
import keyboard
import time
import win32api , win32con
# tile 1 x : 380  y :   650
# tile 2 x : 450  y :   650
# tile 3 x : 530  y :   650
# tile 4 x : 600  y :   650

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)


while keyboard.is_pressed("q") == False :
    if pyautogui.pixel(380,500)[0] == 0:
        click(380,500)
       
    if pyautogui.pixel(450,500)[0] == 0:
        .click(450,500)
        
    if pyautogui.pixel(530,500)[0] == 0:
        click(530,500)
        
    if pyautogui.pixel(600,500)[0] == 0:
        click(600,500)
```

Comment: When you say " i have installed pypiwin32 and pywin32 from PyPi", you mean from pip? Or you just have deployed the packages somehow?

Comment: PyPi is the package manager for python in visual studio 2019 , I installed the modules from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Quinn said, is the package installed? like in the cmd...

```
pip install win32con
pip install win32api
```

Other case can be that you probably didn't check the "ADD TO PATH" during Python installation. If so, you should probably reinstall Python and make sure that "ADD TO PATH" Check box is checked, and try using PIP to install the packages.

Comment: Yes , I have pip , and I installed the packages using pip install in CMD and again from PyPi in visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, how did you installed it? I'm trying as you said, with PyPI in VS 2019 and...

No packages for it :S . Suggests to install with pip, but it fails so...

So, your manager as I figured out, is pip... are you sure you have those installed?

Comment: From PyPi I installed piwin32

Comment: And yes I have pip